# Custom Case Change Due Date button

Tags: custom-button, date, list-view, list-button

I'm trying to create a button that would change the Due Date field of a selected case in a List View. I'm stuck on the URL, since this is a mass change type would there be a custom URL that would be input? I want this button to function just like the change owner example below.

[image]

**Change Owner example:**

[image]

Comment: Unless you want to set all selected cases to the same due date, I don't think this button is going to do what you want. I think you'll only want the button to process one case at a time, not multiple ones.

Comment: I would want the button to process multiple cases at a time.

Comment: you have to try some code at your own to do that, I have given that approach

Comment: I see what you mean, I'll compile the code and update appropriately.

Comment: did you get a chance to solve this? I have solved this at my DE

Comment: I'm just not certain on what I need to customize/change in the code you provided for it to work. I keep getting the "URL No Longer Exists" error.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can take this approach.

1. From your javascript button, launch a flow and pass parameters to the flow.
2. In the flow, place a date field where user can select the date.
3. Finally based on passed parameters you should update the case records.

I have given a code how you can pass parameters (CaseIds) to the flow.

**Code behind javascript button**

```
{!RequireScript("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}

var caseObj = new sforce.SObject("Case");
var selectedCases = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Case)}; //chosen records from list view checkboxes

//check at-least one record is selected
if (selectedCases[0] == null) {
   alert("You must select at least one record");
} else 
{
    var serverUrl = '{!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_260}';
    var position = {!FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260)};
    var base = serverUrl.substring(0,position-1);

    var url = base +encodeURI('/flow/Update_Due_Date?vSelectedCaseIds=' + selectedCases +  '&vCaseCount=' + selectedCases.length +  '&retURL=/500/o');

    window.open(url, '_self');
}
```

Refer this answer for detailed answer:

[Pass Case Ids collection to visual workflow from Case List View Custom Button and update cases taking from input screen](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165270/pass-case-ids-collection-to-visual-workflow-from-case-list-view-custom-button-an/165272#165272)