# Pass Case Ids collection to visual workflow from Case List View Custom Button and update cases taking from input screen

Tags: javascript, custom-button, visual-workflow, collection, parsing

**Requirement**

From Case list View, user will choose one or more cases and will click on "Update Due Date" button, where it will show a screen to choose the "Due Date".

[image: Case List]

Due Date screen

[image: due date screen]

And finally flow will parse the caseIds and update all the cases with the selected due date.

Comment: Since my 'answer' was deleted, I now have to post a comment. I would use the Mass list update function. It's already built in, just be sure you have the same record type as the list criteria and turn on enhanced lists.

Comment: You can put that in answer with details  it that helps to someone,  I have answered this as a purpose of knowledge sharing

Comment: your solution is awesome by the way, however, does this work in Lightning?  I'm assuming not?

Comment: I have done in Classic only, not tested in Lightning. I will also look for that. You can give a try and post your answer as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a List View Custom button and use this code to pass parameters to the flow.

Flow parameters:

> vSelectedCaseIds which contains case ids collection which can be found from `{!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Case)}`.
>
> vCaseCount which contains number of selected case id count.
>
> retURL where it will be landed after completion.

```
{!RequireScript("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}

var caseObj = new sforce.SObject("Case");
var selectedCases = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Case)}; //chosen records from list view checkboxes

//check at-least one record is selected
if (selectedCases[0] == null) {
   alert("You must select at least one record");
} else 
{
    var serverUrl = '{!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_260}';
    var position = {!FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260)};
    var base = serverUrl.substring(0,position-1);

    var url = base +encodeURI('/flow/Update_Due_Date?vSelectedCaseIds=' + selectedCases +  '&vCaseCount=' + selectedCases.length +  '&retURL=/500/o');

    window.open(url, '_self');
}
```

**The complete flow will look like this:**

[image: Flow designer update cases]

Step by step process:

> 1. Screen

[image: choose due date]

> 2. Decision - Check Case Counter size

[image: Check Case Counter size]

> 3. Assignment - Retrieve Single Case Id from param

[image: Retrieve Single Case Id from param]

caseIdFormula - `LEFT({!vRemainingCaseIds}, 15)`

> 4. Assignment - Assign values to Case Object

[image: Assign values to Case Object]

Where `varSObjectCase` is SObject input and output variable

> 5. Assignment - Add All Case Objects

[image: Add All Case Objects]

Where `All_Case_Sobjects` is SObject Collection variable

> 6. Assignment - Retrieve Remaining CaseIds

[image: Retrieve Remaining CaseIds]

Remaining_CaseIds - Formula

```
TRIM(
RIGHT({!vRemainingCaseIds}, (LEN({!vRemainingCaseIds})-16))
)
```

> 7. Decision - If Counter less than vCaseCount

[image: If Counter less than vCaseCount]

> 8. Fast Update

[image: Fast Update]

> 9. Success

[image: Success]